# QuickSort Code (Python)

Tags: python, quicksort

this is my first post on StackExchange, and I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with my code for a simple QuickSort program. I'm fairly sure that some integer simply needs to be adjusted by +-1 or something, so I'd like to keep the format.

The code is as follows:

```
def QuickSort(Array_1,lower=0,upper=-1):
    print(Array_1)
    if upper==-1:
        upper=len(Array_1)-1
    if lower<upper:
        Array_2,pivot=partition(Array_1,lower,upper)
        Array_3=QuickSort(Array_2,lower,pivot-1)
        Array_4=QuickSort(Array_3,pivot+1,upper)
        return Array_4
    else:
        return Array_1

def partition(Array,lower,upper):
    key=Array[upper]
    print(Array)
    i=lower
    j=lower-1
    z=0
    for j in range(lower,upper-1):
        print(i)
        print(j)
        if Array[j]<key:
            Array[i],Array[j]=Array[j],Array[i]
            i+=1
    Array[upper],Array[i]=Array[i],Array[upper]
    print(Array)
return (Array,i+1)
```

Additionally, one thing I noticed is that the code runs infinitely if I change the 'j in range(p,r-1)' to 'j in range(p,r)', but it doesn't look like it should. Thoughts?

Variables have been edited to meaningful variables. I think They were all changed correctly.

```
 input: [8, 18, 6, 19]
 desired output: [6,8,18,19]
 output: [19, 8, 18, 6]

 input: [16, 0, 20, 10, 5, 2]
 desired output: [0,2,5,10,16,20]
 output: [2, 0, 20, 16, 10, 5]
```

Comment: use meaningful variable names ... single letter variable names means someone has to go actually look up the algorithm for you... most of us havent had an algorithms class in quite some time so the implementation of quicksort isnt something we just have floating in our heads(especially since this has no value other than a learning excersize)

Comment: thats better (I know its probably obvious to you since you are taking the class or just covered the algorithm somewhere) ... now add an example call to your quicksort and the output you get (and potentially what you expect if its not immediatly obvious)

Comment: Can you give us sample input, output with your code, and expected output? Just something simple like `[4,5,3,1,2]` or etc

Comment: Code comments, docstrings, also go a long way towards figuring out if what you intended to do is what you are doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were only small errors in your `partition` function as you already guessed:

1) Your `for` loop was not processing the last element because you used `range(lower, upper-1)` instead of `range(lower, upper)`

2) You should finally return `i` instead of `i+1`

```
def partition(Array,lower,upper):
    ...
    for j in range(lower,upper):
    ...
    return (Array,i)
```

Results:

```
>>> print QuickSort([8, 18, 6, 19])
[6, 8, 18, 19]
```

and

```
>>> print QuickSort([16, 0, 20, 10, 5, 2])
[0, 2, 5, 10, 16, 20]
```